# How is React handling renders for this uncontrolled input element?

Tags: reactjs, input, render

I'm going through React's beta docs and would like to better understand how react handles user's interactions with the UI. Specifically with this non-controlled input field.

Note:

- the input field is not disabled
- new input values should not trigger a render, because it's not changing any state (local variables are ignored)

So, then why is the change not reflected in the UI???

The code is bellow, and an interactive "sandbox" can be found here: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-a-components-memory under challenge #2 at the bottom of the page.

```
export default function Form() {
  let firstName = '';
  let lastName = '';

  function handleFirstNameChange(e) {
    firstName = e.target.value;
  }

  function handleLastNameChange(e) {
    lastName = e.target.value;
  }

  function handleReset() {
    firstName = '';
    lastName = '';
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      <input
        placeholder="First name"
        value={firstName}
        onChange={handleFirstNameChange}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Last name"
        value={lastName}
        onChange={handleLastNameChange}
      />
      <h1>Hi, {firstName} {lastName}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

To be clear, I'm not asking *how* to solve this problem; I know how to hook it up and fix it with state. I am interested in what's preventing the input field from updating with a new value.

On initial render it receives the empty string as its value. But then why doesn't it change when a user types?

Here's two non-react input fields, one with a value attribute, and one where the value is set by JS. Both can be modified:

```
<input type="text" value="editable">

<input type="text" id="input2">

<script>
 document.getElementById('input2').value = "also editable"
</script>
```

So, why isn't the input editable in react?

Comment: These inputs are controlled! Here you control them `value={firstName}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for a component to render:

- It’s the component’s initial render.
- The component’s (or one of its ancestors’) state has been updated.

In your example, the second condition is not met and react has no way of knowing your input values changed, it does not re render, and so does not commit changes to the DOM.
Note that react is [wrapping event handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), it does not work exactly like vanilla JavaScript

Comment: Right, but it's an uncontrolled input. There is no state hooked up to it, and if I remove the value provided by the local variable (the "value={}" part) from the input entirely, then I will be able to modify it like any regular html input field. So, no state will be changed just as before, but input changes will be visible in the UI! I don't get why, since both times there's no re-render, and there's no governing state.

Comment: JSX is the react internal representation of the DOM, sometimes called virtual DOM, not the DOM itself. React is responsible to commit changes trough render and your component does not re render

Comment: so why is it editable in one case, but not the other? Both without state, and both seemingly not triggering a render?

Comment: By passing a value to the input, react will consider it controlled, it will not update unless state changes. It does not matter that your component has state or not since you are passing a value, it will be treated as part of the state of the component

Comment: It sounds like a smart way to safeguard against errors of having an input that doesn't link to some storage, and probably why defaultValue exists as a separate thing. But, I'd like to learn more about this behaviour. You know where I can find it in docs?